# How to Renew RapidSSL Certificate without upgrading the Android app?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, ca

I have Rapid SSL CA certificate installed in the server and corresponding certificate is kept in the app in the assets folder. The app is published in Google Playstore, sometimes back.
However, this certificate is going to be expired in few days and we don’t have any plan to upload new build version to Google Play immediately. 
Is there any way to renew/extend the expiry date of the current certificate installed in the server side? So that build present in the Google Playstore will work properly even after certificate renew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that you would like to **extend your certificate expiry date** without **re-issue** but it is not possible certainly. In your case, you must have to renew your certificate before an SSL certificate expire. For user convenience, Certificate Authority offers SSL for multiple years.

**Renewing an SSL certificate** is the same process, when you buy brand new SSL certificate for first time for a website or app.

Please follow below steps to get **renew your certificate**.

- Renew your **RapidSSL Certificate** with any SSL Certificate provider at lowest available price (let’s say CheapSSLSecurity), Please make sure to buy it for multiple years to avoid installation per year.
- Then generate a new **CSR** and **Private Key**. Use that new CSR and Private key to install your SSL Certificate on your Android App.

***Note:*** If you will purchase the **RapidSSL Certificate** for **multiple** years (three year), then you don’t need to install it again till the upcoming three years.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. Helped a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a new CSR (you can use old CSR but it is not recommended) while renewing your SSL Certificate. So, SSL certificate issued by RapidSSL with new CSR should be installed properly on server. You should only uninstall your old certificate after new certificate is installed properly.

Unfortunately there is no such facility to extend expiry date without following above technique. So, in my suggestion you will have to upload new certificate on your server but fortunately you don’t need to do anything for your application. Properly installed SSL Certificate on your server will help your app to fetch data and run securely.